# Regular cardinals exponentiation.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, cardinals

I am struggling with an exercise regarding cardinal exponentiation when one of the two is regular. The exercise reads:

*Let $k$, $\lambda$ be cardinals, with $k$ regular and $\lambda < k$. Prove that $k^{\lambda} = \sum_{\alpha<k}|\alpha|^{\lambda}$* .

I still have to get familiar with cofinalities and regular cardinals so I may be missing something very obvious, but I don't know where to start. Any help is very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

1. What do you know about $\operatorname{cf}(\lambda)$ compared to $\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)$?
2. If $f: \lambda \to \kappa$ is a function, what can you say about the range of $f$?
3. Using 2, can you write such $f$ as a function between a different domain and/or codomain?

Comment: 1. I know that $cf(k) = k > \lambda \ge cf(\lambda)$ 2. f is bounded. 3. I think I have to change the codomain, but I really can't figure out how to get any summation :/

Comment: @cento18 That's right, and what does being bounded mean for the codomain? What is the definition of the summation?

Comment: Ok I think I'm onto something. By definition $\sum_{\alpha<k}|\alpha|^{\lambda} = |\bigcup_{\alpha<k}({\alpha}\times|\alpha|^{\lambda})|$. I'll refer to the set inside the cardinality symbol on the right hand side as $union$. So now I have to show an injection from $k^{\lambda}$ to $union$ and viceversa and this will conclude the equality between their cardinalities, i.e. the required result.

Comment: First, take $f\in union$, since the $\alpha$'s are ordinals, this means that there is some $\alpha<k$ s.t. $f=(\alpha, f_1)$ where $f_1\in |\alpha|^{\lambda}$. But $\alpha<k$ implies $|\alpha|< k$ and so $|\alpha|^{\lambda} \subseteq k^{\lambda}$. So, the map that to each $f\in union$ associate the corresponding $f_1$ as above is injective, concluding the first domination.

Comment: As for the other domination, take any $f\in k^{\lambda}$, for what we said above, $f$ is bounded, i.e. $ran(f) \subseteq \alpha$ for some $\alpha<k$, but this means that $k^{\lambda} \subseteq |\alpha|^{\lambda}$ (here I am not sure why I can pass to the cardinality of $\alpha$ instead of $\alpha$ only). So the function that to each $f\in k^{\lambda}$ associate $(\alpha, f)$ is injective concluding the exercise. Is what I did correct in any way? Also as mentioned above I don't how to justify the fact the passage from $\alpha$ to $|\alpha|$ in the second domination. Thx :)

Comment: @cento18 Yes, that is the solution! There is a typo in your union, that should say $| \bigcup_{\alpha < \kappa} (\{\alpha\} \times |\alpha|^\lambda)|$. For your final question: there is a bijection $g: \alpha \to |\alpha|$, this induces a bijection $g_*: \alpha^\lambda \to |\alpha|^\lambda$ by $g_*(f) = gf$.

Comment: Yeah that makes very much sense, thank you very much for the help!